# Hibernate Statistics | hibernate.generate_statistics | Why Entities Flushed?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have loaded 100k records into memory. It was single table and just ran select * on that table using named query. At end of loading i get following statistics: (This takes 22 Minutes to execute)

```
2020-09-22 11:12:59,398 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener] (EJB default - 10) Session Metrics {
    3317327 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections; <- One connection picked from pool
    73211 nanoseconds spent releasing 1 JDBC connections; <- This is done after select*
    3477124 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements; <- This is for createStatement
    141528764799 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements; <- This is for st.executeQuery()
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches; <- ?
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts; <- ?
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits; <- ?
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses; <- ?
    27996423 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 15814 entities and 0 collections); <- ?
    11580 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections) <- ?
}
```

As there are 100k records so we should have 100k entities but in flush it says 15814 entities. What is the meaning of it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not reproducible without some additional details related to your project.

I tried it with `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production` and hibernate `5.4.10.Final`.

Database setup:

```sql
create table MY_TEST_TABLE
(
   RECID number,
   MESSAGE varchar2(4000),
   TECHID varchar2(16),

   constraint MY_TEST_TABLE_PK primary key(RECID)
);
------
SET serveroutput ON format WRAPPED
declare

begin
  for ind in 1 .. 100000
  loop
     insert into MY_TEST_TABLE
     values (ind, 'Message ' || ind, 'T' || ind);
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
/
```

Native query:

```java
List<TestTable> results = em.createNativeQuery(
    "select RECID, MESSAGE, TECHID from MY_TEST_TABLE",
     TestTable.class)
.getResultList();
```

Hibernate statistics output:

```
19:13:02,330  INFO StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener:258 - Session Metrics {
    56000 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    106200 nanoseconds spent releasing 1 JDBC connections;
    39460800 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    5975300 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    32090352100 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 100000 entities and 0 collections);
    60000 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```